# Build RViz plugin from .ui file

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view, ros-kinetic, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My existing solution simply designs the GUI in qtcreator and then use the `uic` to generate the [dotnect_window.h (link to plugin)](https://github.com/ItsmeJulian/dotnect_stack/tree/dev/dotnect_rviz_plugin) which I might have to modify to derive from `class ...  : public rviz::Panel`. How to automate this / do it all?

For example `rqt_image_view` already uses an .ui file, but it is rqt standalone. So I started with the RViz plugin *teleop* and added code from `rqt_image_view`  . Maybe I could use the uncommented `qt4/5_wrap_ui` as a start? Just to give an idea:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rviz_dotnect_plugin)

# ros packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rviz
)

catkin_package(
   # INCLUDE_DIRS
   # LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
   CATKIN_DEPENDS rviz
   # DEPENDS
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)

link_directories(
  ${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

# Bundle headers .h
set(HEADER_FILES
  include/drive_widget.h
  include/teleop_panel.h
)

# Automatically enable Qt's Meta-Object Compiler moc generation
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Avoid keyword definition to avaid conflicts with boost or xapian etc
# e.g. http://muddyazian.blogspot.de/2012/04/getting-qt-app-working-with-boost-using.html
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

# Use same QT version as rviz and specify headers run through MOC.
# MOC generated .cpp files are included automatically as headers.
if(rviz_QT_VERSION VERSION_LESS "5")
  message(STATUS "Using Qt4 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: ${rviz_QT_VERSION}")
  find_package(Qt4 ${rviz_QT_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED QtCore QtGui)
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  qt4_wrap_cpp(HEADER_FILES_MOCS ${HEADER_FILES})
  #qt4_wrap_ui(rqt_image_view_UIS_H ${rqt_image_view_UIS})
else()
  message(STATUS "Using Qt5 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: ${rviz_QT_VERSION}")
  find_package(Qt5 ${rviz_QT_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED Core Widgets)
  set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
  qt5_wrap_cpp(HEADER_FILES_MOCS ${HEADER_FILES})
  #qt5_wrap_ui(rqt_image_view_UIS_H ${rqt_image_view_UIS})
endif()

# Bundle source .cpp including the mocs
set(SOURCE_FILES
src/drive_widget.cpp
src/teleop_panel.cpp
${HEADER_FILES_MOCS}
)

# A rviz plugin is a shared library named ${PROJECT_NAME}.so
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Link executable with Qt libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${QT_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

## Install rules...
```

I went on and generated the header from .ui via `$ uic -o dotnect_window.h dotnect_window.ui`. But  `uic` deprecated the -i arg to generate the implementation file via `uic -i PizzaEntry.h -o PizzaEntry.cpp pizza.ui`. Argl.

Also the [third step](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Using%20.ui%20file%20in%20rqt%20plugin) is nowhere to be found inside `rqt_image_view`. 
I get confused with what is a rqt standalone and what I actually need to just get the rviz plugin as`rviz::Panel` building from .ui.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241811/build-rviz-plugin-from-.ui-file/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-16**:
You definitely shouldn't be doing the conversion from .ui files to C++ code manually; the build system should do that for you. I don't do much work with QT, but the qt4/5_wrap_ui rules look like the right place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here a sample `CMakeLists.txt` which allowed us to create `rviz` panels, I'm not quite sure what you need to adapt, however, we had no manual copying to do. Seems like you are missing the `MOC_FILES` and the `UIC_FILES` at the `add_library()` call...

Note that this is Qt4 only, but I guess the Qt5 way should be pretty similar...

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

set(
  HEADER_FILES
  src/my_panel.h
)

# required if you want to add some images, etc. Could be made differently/nicer, probably.
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resource/*.resource)

qt4_add_resources(
  QT_RESOURCES_CPP
  ${QT_RESOURCES}
)

qt4_wrap_cpp(
  MOC_FILES
  ${HEADER_FILES}
)

qt4_wrap_ui(
  UIC_FILES
  resource/my_panel.ui
)

set(
  SOURCE_FILES
  src/my_panel.cpp
)

add_library(my_panel ${SOURCE_FILES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${MOC_FILES} ${UIC_FILES})

target_link_libraries(my_panell ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

# maybe you also need a add_dependencies() call, we did not...
```

---

EDIT

Note that this is implemented as a `QWidget`.
Some more templates:

Our header `my_panel.h`:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <rviz/panel.h>

namespace Ui
{
class MyPanelUi;
}

namespace my_panel
{

class MyPanel: public rviz::Panel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyPanel( QWidget* parent = 0 );
  
  ~MyPanel();
  
protected:
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;

  Ui::MyPanelUi *ui_;
  
private Q_SLOTS:
  // Q_SLOTS for interaction with buttons, etc.
  void gui_button_stop();

  // your custom stuff
}; // MyPanel

}  // my_panel
```

The `my_panel.cpp`

```
#include "my_panel.h"

#include "ui_my_panel.h"

#include <QMessageBox>

namespace my_panel
{

MyPanel::MyPanel( QWidget* parent )
  : rviz::Panel( parent )
  , ui_(new Ui::MyPanelUi())
{
  // set up the GUI
  ui_->setupUi(this);

  // connecting the signals to the respectiv SLOTs
  /*
   * Main Control Buttons *
   */
  // the button is called pushButton_stop in the ui file
  connect( ui_->pushButton_stop, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( gui_button_stop() ));
}
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-08-19**:
Great, extensive answer. I will try to port the code and will post the updates once I got first results.

**Comment by [demorise](https://answers.ros.org/users/34609/demorise/) on 2022-04-14**:
Thanks! This really helped.